# How to store all and multiple response data using setProperty Function in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, rest-api

Here is the scenario :

20 users with one thread group and 6 driver with other thread group here interlink the thread group with `beanshell Assertion` with `setproperty` method so from 20 user is generating 20 pickup id.

So here is the response- `{"error":"200","error_description":"7000"}`

I'm getting for 20 it is like 7001,7002,7003.....7020 but I am sending this pick up id to next thread group by using `${__property(PickUpId_value)}` so here 6 driver accepting the same pick id that is 7020  last one. this the against the functionality how to over come this problem.

Is there any way that `${_property()}` store all the generated pick up id and assign different pick up id to all the 6 drivers in next Thread group ? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend switching to JSR223 Assertion and Groovy language as:

- Since JMeter 3.1 [it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- [Groovy has built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) so you will be able to parse responses without using any extra test elements or libraries
- [Groovy performs much better than Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

So if use the following Groovy code in the JSR223 Assertion:

```
def threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName()
threadName = threadName.substring(threadName.lastIndexOf('-') + 1)

def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
props.put('PickUpId_value_' + threadName, response.error_description)
```

It will generate the following (or similar) JMeter Properties:

```
PickUpId_value_1=7000
PickUpId_value_2=7001
PickUpId_value_3=7002
PickUpId_value_4=7003
PickUpId_value_5=7004
```

So you will be able to refer it using i.e. [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) like `${__P(PickUpId_value_${__threadNum},)}` or any JMeter Variable, for example [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) reference name like `${__P(PickUpId_value_${someCounterValue},)}`

Comment: here i am using like this  ${__pickUpId_value_${counter},)} but it is not happening. pick up id is not passing inside the request

Comment: it is showing like this "pickupid":""

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T you made my day .....you always helped  me  to complete my task thanks lot once again

Comment: i just use __counter() function it is working form me

Comment: Hi... Dmitri i asked one more question please help me to sort out  that problem

Comment: Hi...Dimitri T  is there any possible that extract the error description when error is 200 please tell